# Kotlin coroutines Mutex owner usage

Tags: kotlin, mutex, kotlin-coroutines

What is the expected usage of `owner` in a `kotlinx.coroutines.sync.Mutex`?

From what I understand a `Mutex.withLock` will make any calling coroutine after the first (witch locked the mutex), await until it is unlocked, and then hold the lock themselves.

So, what could be causing the following error?

```
2019-12-06 15:29:30.508 6380-6840/com.[...] E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-3
    Process: com.[...], PID: 6380
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already locked by [...].source.local.configuration.ConfigurationCacheSourceImpl@c86499c
        at kotlinx.coroutines.sync.MutexImpl.lockSuspend(Mutex.kt:208)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.sync.MutexImpl.lock(Mutex.kt:187)
        at com.[...].source.local.cache.CacheSource.invoke$suspendImpl(CacheSource.kt:52)
        at com.[...].source.local.cache.CacheSource.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.[...].source.local.cache.ICacheSource$DefaultImpls.invoke$default(CacheSource.kt:10)
        at com.[...].repository.ConfigurationRepositoryImpl.getStuff(ConfigurationRepository.kt:14)
        at com.[...].interactor.ConfigurationInteractorImpl.getStuff(CongifurationInteractor.kt:16)
        at com.[...]
        at com.[...]
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740)
```

Note, that I am always using the same `owner`on its `withLock` calls, as per:

```
abstract class CacheSource<T>(
    private val cacheMutex = Mutex()

    override suspend operator fun invoke(
        [...]
    ): T = cacheMutex.withLock(this) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

And as per [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/):

> owner - Optional owner token for debugging. When owner is specified (non-null value) and this mutex is already locked with the same token (same identity), this function throws IllegalStateException.

Comment: Is the mutex re-entrant?

Comment: according to the [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/), no

Comment: Then there's your answer: `mutex.withLock(this) { mutex.withLock(this) { ... } }` should throw the exception and thus give you a better indication of programmer error than just deadlocking.

Comment: I think I understand what re-entrant means, and if so, I am also sure that the code inside the mutex lock never calls itself or any other mutex.

Comment: Why don't you post your full stack trace? Are you even getting the exception? The actual topic of your question is pretty vague.

Comment: Sure, I updated the question. I think the problem is related to the `owner`, it's just that I don`t understand what the owner should be or is for.

Comment: The owner should be scoped to the coroutine taking the lock. If you pass the same one from all coroutines, it will throw the exception instead of awaiting to get the lock. The point of passing the owner object is the one I mentioned above, getting exceptions instead of deadlocks.

Comment: So the owner is a protection against deadlocks? Meaning each thread calling the function should use a different one to protect the thread's coroutines from waiting forever?

Comment: The owner of a coroutine mutex isn't a thread but a coroutine. So the owner object you pass in must correspond to one distinct coroutine. That way, if the same coroutine tries to reenter it, you'll get an error instead of a deadlock. You can also omit this argument entirely and get deadlocks for incorrect code.

Comment: Thank you! That does clarify things a lot. I suppose I should only pass a specific owner If I want to limit the mutex usage to something else.

Comment: I think the best practice is to pass in something that corresponds to the coroutine, so you get any re-entry attempts signaled as exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the `owner` in `Mutex` is explained in the documentation of the corresponding parameters. Coroutine mutexes are non-reentrant and so it is relatively easy to get into a "deadlock" while trying to reacquire the lock that is already acquired. Also, while implementing complex locking patterns like hand-over locking it might be easy to mess up and release a lock you were not supposed to hold.

So `owner` is an optional aid for debugging. When `owner` is specified (non-null value) and the mutex is already locked with the same owner (same identity), then `lock` function throws `IllegalStateException`. Similarly, attempting to `unlock` with a wrong owner throws `IllegalStateException`.

See the documentation on `lock` and `unlock` functions for details:

- https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/lock.html
- https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/unlock.html

Comment: I appreciate the explanation, but I must also say that (most) of this is not in the official docs or tutorials, and while perhaps obvious to someone familiar with mutexes, it certainly is confusing to a newcomer like me.

Comment: The owner is an optional parameter that is intended only for advanced use-cases. I don't see any reason to have a tutorial for a feature like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mutex.holdsLock check owner is already locked, you can't lock the same owner while owner is locked.